# in app purchase ios download content after user purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm working In-App Purchase, i follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). Its working well.

I have no. of videos in my project I put all my videos in my App. now my app size is comes around 850MB.

Now the user going to buy the paid version or not, But every users need to download the 850MB size app. I think its not good practice

Is it possible to change, after user buy the product we can download the videos to App. I hope it will reduce the size of app initially and good work too.

Can any one help me for this ?

Comment: Will you consider DRM & streaming option ? Then user does not require to download whole file to play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple can host your in-app purchase content, if it is non consumable. This way, when the user buy the content through in-app purchase, it will be downloaded.

Have a look at [this step-by-step guide](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_and_Creating_App_Store_Hosted_Content_for_iOS_6_In-App_Purchases).

Comment: Hi Thanks for replaying. its working but right now in that product list not contain the newly add product(That product only i post content). it shows status as "Processing Content". Need to wait until its change ? Also i want to know I need to do code for download the product ?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Building_In-App_Purchasing_into_iPhone_iOS_6_Applications -- you need code to download the product and also to unzip the downloaded content...